# Image button in css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to create image button in css file of mvc4? I am trying to do so but the image is not being displayed.

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="button" style="width:48px;    height:48px" >
<img src="~/Images/Setting.jpg"/></button>
```

Comment: make sure url is correct of image

Answer (score 0):

You may use `background-image`

Demo

```css
button {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button name="button" type="submit" class="button" style="width:48px;    height:48px">button</button>
```

Comment: The image is still not being shown. The button is appearing like a white box.

Comment: This is working fine for me, may be wait for a while to allow the image to load.

Comment: I checked it. It is showing your image as mentioned in URL but not mine which is placed in Images folder of project.

Comment: have you tried moving the image to the same directory as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input name="button" type="submit" class="button" value="your_text" />
<style>
.button{
width:48px;
height:48px;
background: url(/Images/Setting.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

i just set the width and height in img tag too.